# sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sql

Having an issue with `sqlsrv_query`. This is the error I get:

> PHP Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Here is the relevant code:

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));
$recordcount = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: what `sqlsrv_errors()` returns?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on [`sqlsrv_query()`](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query) has everything you need to know.

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a statement resource on success and **FALSE if an error occurred**.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```